# Is it possible to assign a function to the object instance itself?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Consider the following:

```
function Person() {
    this.talk = function() {
        alert('talking');
    }
}

var person = new Person();

person(); // Make this alert 'standing'

person.talk();
```

Is it possible to assign a function to the instance itself while preservering the object properties/methods and the prototype chain?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a function object and return it instead, like this

```
function Person() {

    // Create a function object
    var F = function() {
        console.log('standing');
    }

    // Add attributes to the function object
    F.talk = function() {
        console.log('talking');
    }

    // Return the function object itself
    return F;
}

var person = new Person();

person();
# standing

person.talk();
# talking
```

Since `Person` constructor function returns a function object, that itself can be executed. That is why `person()` is working.

**Note:**

Since we are returning a function *Object*, from the function, we can invoke it without the `new` keyword as well. So, the following will be working exactly like the previous way

```
var person = Person();
person();
person.talk();
```

Comment: for what is the new operator if you are returning an function an cut off the prototype?

Comment: @ThorstenArtner'Austria' It doesn't matter how we invoke it, it will work fine. And `new` is there because OP was invoking it like that. Anyway, added a note in the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: i dont see any sense in your answer since it is the same like in my post below cutting of the prototype and dont have any class of Person, just normal function reference

Comment: @ThorstenArtner'Austria' What do you think `var person=Person;` in your answer do?

Comment: @FelixKling Agreed, but he is not worried about Inheritance I believe. Though I have no idea what exactly he is trying to do.

Comment: @thefourtheye  person=Person is referring to the Person function instead of creating always a new same function and its the same sense as in your answer. if you really want a class the question of the op cant be realized

Comment: @ThorstenArtner'Austria': Not really. Since the OP used a constructor function, we can assume that he actually wants to create multiple "instances" of `Person`. In your case, there would always only be one instance.

Comment: @Felix Kling yes ;), the instances are all functions and the same functions. does this make sense?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that the prototype chain should be kept as well. :( This is a good answer otherwise... Edited the question now. Sorry!

Comment: @user2906759 Unfortunately it is not possible. Sorry!!

Answer (score 0):

```
function Person ()
 {
 alert ("standing");
 }

Person.talk=function () {alert ("talk");}

var person=Person;
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the prototype chain should be kept. Edited the question now. Sorry!